# Intent.EXTRA_CC not populating cc field in android app

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I'm pre-filling an email which should launch in the users default email app but for some reason the CC line isn't populating with it's intended string. Any Idea what's going on?

```
Intent toSupportIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:" +  getString(R.string.support_email)));
toSupportIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, getString(R.string.cc_support_email));
toSupportIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.support_email_subject));
toSupportIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.support_email_message));
startActivity(toSupportIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ACTION_SENDTO` [is not documented to support `EXTRA_CC`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO). Hence, you should not be surprised when it does not work with all apps.

Comment: I'm not finding another way to do what I'm trying to do. What would you suggest?

Comment: @MBW: You could try [encoding it in the `mailto:` link](http://blog.escapecreative.com/customizing-mailto-links/).